# React app does not re-render a child component if it was added dynamically

Tags: reactjs, rendering

We are developing a chatbot. Some steps should be able to be repeated, so some steps should be added dynamically. We found the following solution (simplified version)

- Chat messages are stored in `useState()`:

```
const [components, addComponent] = setComponent();
```

- Render it via `.map()`:

```
components.map((component, index) => (
    <React.Fragment key={index}>{component}</React.Fragment>
))
```

- Add new elements to `useEffect()`:

```
useEffect(() => {
    setComponent(<Message count={count} />);
}, []);
```

But we have a big problem: the *required re-rendering* (term taken from this article: https://www.developerway.com/posts/react-re-renders-guide) is not happening inside `<Message />`. For example, in `<Message />` we passed the prop `count` with value 1, and after a while we changed the value to 2. In the parent component, the value will change, and in `<Message />`  - remains 1

Here you can clearly see the bug - https://codesandbox.io/s/wild-shadow-gfj59f?file=/src/App.tsx:528-553. In theory, in the console we should see the following sequence: "Container 1", "Message 1", "Container 2", "Message 2". And instead we see: "Container 1", "Message 1", "Container 2"

We found a solution to this bug: to change the state of `<Message />`, use not props from the parent component, but use the context. But this solution also has a cost: you need to rewrite a lot of code

**Question**. Is there any solution where you can dynamically add new components to the array and still be able to pass props to those components? Maybe React has some methods to return the relationship between the container component and the dynamically added child component?